# Mean of column subsets for all columns of a 2D Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to take the mean of every 2 elements in each column

Here's an array for convenience:

```
p = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
              [10, 12, 21, 12, 11, 51],
              [743,123,1,42,12,9],
             [51, 21, 31, 13, 12, 10], 
             [76, 12 , 11,88, 90, 12]])
```

I want to get the mean of every two consecutive elements for every column:

```
p[0][0:2].mean() # mean of first 2 elements of the 1st column
```

This is what I have achieved (thanks to [sirfz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40953115/1886529)) to do though I'd like to get rid of the for loop if possible (using numpy only?) and getting back a numpy array without having to do it manually:

```
parr = p[-1,:];
for i in range(3-1):
    tmp = p[i*2:i*2+2,:].mean(axis=0)
    parr = np.vstack([parr, tmp])
parr = np.roll(parr, -1, axis = 0)
```

which returns

```
array([[   5.5,    7. ,   12. ,    8. ,    8. ,   28.5],
       [ 397. ,   72. ,   16. ,   27.5,   12. ,    9.5],
       [  76. ,   12. ,   11. ,   88. ,   90. ,   12. ]])
```

**Update**: I ended up editing the accepted answer to accomodate taking the mean over a larger number of elements. The problem with the accepted answer was the individual row or column in case of an odd number of rows or columns.

```
ii = 2 # number of elements to average
if rows % 2 != 0:
    rows -= 1
    parr = p[:rows].reshape((np.int(rows/ii), ii, cols)).mean(axis=1)
    parr = np.vstack([parr, p[-1]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) method takes an `axis` argument. From what I understand, what you're looking for is:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.random.randn(20, 30)
means = p[:, :10].mean(axis=1)
```

The above yields a result similar to:

```
array([-0.45358033,  0.08746795,  0.04517895,  0.08501094, -0.16296425,
        0.48717193,  0.4581073 ,  0.24285689,  0.46419295, -0.51888609,
       -0.04200014, -0.64716378,  0.09296176, -0.53195615,  0.3466912 ,
        0.38070856, -0.80346158, -0.47310487,  0.13224299,  0.09014788])
```

To answer your updated question, it can be done without loops as follows:

```
p = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
              [10, 12, 21, 12, 11, 51],
              [743,123,1,42,12,9],
              [51, 21, 31, 13, 12, 10], 
              [76, 12 , 11,88, 90, 12]])
rows, columns = p.shape
# check if rows of p is divisible by 2
if rows % 2 != 0:
    # duplicate last row to be included in mean
    p = np.vstack([p, p[-1]])
    # we added a new row
    rows += 1
mean = p.reshape((rows / 2, 2, columns)).mean(axis=1)
```

This solution is 2.2 to 3.6x faster than the loop approach on my computer.

Perhaps with further meddling you can come up with a more improved solution but this should help.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helps me get rid of one loop but I still need one to loop over the the whole column. (PS: Your answer flips my need but helps). I updated the question too.

Comment: @user10853 checkout my updated solution to your question, hope this helps

Comment: I ended editing it slight. I left stacking the row (& column) to the end of the if statement because I am working on a larger array and want the mean of a larger subset.
By the way, isn't there a function to do something similar in numpy or pandas or any other module?

Comment: If I knew of one I would've used it in my answer :p